Rebasing sometimes results in foreign commits being commited to my branch?
Basically I noticed that when I try to commit my changes and push them into my feature branch sometimes other people's commits will be commited as well after rebasing.
E.g.:

I work on feature branch, modifying "X" class
Somebody merges something to master, modifying "Y" class
So I git checkout master
git pull
git checkout feature branch
git rebase master

And after these steps when I try to push, the IDE will tell me that "X" and "Y" class related commits will be pushed into my remote branch.
I would like to emphasize that this behavior is random, so sometimes it occurs, sometimes it does not.
What could be the problem? Am I doing something wrong?

"the IDE will tell me" What is "the IDE" and how does it "tell" you this? What exactly does it "tell" you? Please state exactly what you say to Git (or whatever) and what Git (or whatever) says to you in reply.

Git might include commits from the master branch due to conflicts or how the changes are applied.
Follow the below steps,

git rebase -i master - Inorder to avoid this issue
git status - Then check your changes
git log - after rebasing
git pull --rebase - to streamline the process

